# Painting Fractions on Canvas / Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, math, canvas, textbox

I am developing an advanced calculator, and I would like the user to be able to use actual **Vulgar Fractions and Complex Fractions**, that would look like this :

[image]

Most preferably, I'd like to be able to create a backbone of a fraction, with an empty nominator and denominator that the user would be able to click onto and input values into and the fractions to be able to be nested (like in the picture above). How do I approach this topic? A user control / class / something else?

Also, should I choose Canvas or a certain TextBox as an input field?

Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Have you researched some math rendering engine? Look at `TeX` (`LaTeX`) renderer for Windows. You may be able to find a component that does what you need. Writing this from scratch may not be that easy... Good luck.

Comment: Excellent thought from nurchi.  I'd recommend KaTeX, a faster new incarnation from Khan Academy: https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX